# Create tuple from key-value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with dictionary inside, with the following keys: `id`, `external_id_client`, `product_id`, as below:

```
[{'id': 3, 'external_id_client': '7298', 'product_id': 13}, 
{'id': 3, 'external_id_client': '7298', 'product_id': 8}, 
{'id': 4, 'external_id_client': '3', 'product_id': 12}, 
{'id': 4, 'external_id_client': '3', 'product_id': 9}, 
{'id': 5, 'external_id_client': '4', 'product_id': 12}]
```

I need that if the `ID` and `external_id` are repeated and I have information in the `product_id` key it creates a tuple in the `product_id`.

Expected output:

```
[{'id': 3, 'external_id_client': '7298', 'product_id': (13, 8)}, 
{'id': 4, 'external_id_client': '3', 'product_id': (12, 9)}, 
{'id': 5, 'external_id_client': '4', 'product_id': (12)}]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [
    {'id': 3, 'external_id_client': '7298', 'product_id': 13}, 
    {'id': 3, 'external_id_client': '7298', 'product_id': 8}, 
    {'id': 4, 'external_id_client': '3', 'product_id': 12}, 
    {'id': 4, 'external_id_client': '3', 'product_id': 9}, 
    {'id': 5, 'external_id_client': '4', 'product_id': 12}
]

result = [
    {
        "id": itemid, 
        "external_id_client": client,
        "product_id": tuple(item["product_id"] for item in group)
    }
    for (itemid, client), group 
        in groupby(lst, key = lambda item: (item["id"], item["external_id_client"]))
]
```

Comment: Perfect! The only problem is that when it only has a number it has a comma at the end, for example: (9,), is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is just a notation in the output. A tuple with one member is always encoded like that to make the difference with just a parenthesed expression. It's python syntax.